# Netsparker tool shows cookie is not marked as HttpOnly

Tags: java, cookies, httponly

I have downloaded a trial version of Netsparker and scan my Java application with it.

I have created a secure cookie by setting `HTTPOnly` to `true` in web.xml as suggested by many websites.

When I check the application with Firebug, it shows the HttpOnly flag, but in the test report of Netsparker the cookie is not marked as HttpOnly.

How to fix this issue? Why is Netsparker reporting this as vulnerability and telling me I need to fix it? Are there other ways to test it?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note that, Secure and HTTPOnly are two different attributes for a cookie.
Besides that, there may be more than one cookies on your application. Make sure you set HTTPOnly flag for all the cookies.